# facebook callback_url is not called for real time updates via app subscriptions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, callback, subscription

I am fairly new to fb app development and I am trying to get real time updates from my page via app using subscriptions. So I created a subscription first which works fine and I got success, it calls my localserver for the verification.

[image]
and when I see subscriptions on app it shows the following output which I guess is correct.
[image]

Now this app is added on my fb page so once I go to tab my POST request is called,
[image]

Since I have subscribed to feed,name which means any new post or change in page name will trigger a POST request to my callback_url whcih is not happening, please let me know what I am doing wrong.

UPDATE:
just an update my callback url is now hit by facebook but I am not getting any useful object in JSON

```
JSON:{"bufferSize":8192,"contentWritten":0,"status":200,"committed":false,"outputStream":{},"locale":"en_US","finished":false,"headerNames":[],"characterEncoding":"ISO-8859-1"}
```

Comment: Did you change anything to start receiving hits on your callback url?

Comment: No I didnt change anything, you can reach me on pulkit.sharva@gmail.com, after looking at your config may be I can help u